# IOU for two ellipses overlap in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, overlap, ellipse

I was looking for some C++ built-in or implemented functions for calculating two ellipses overlap according to IOU (Intersection Over Union) a.k.a. Jaccard's Coefficient and I got to find it implemented, apparently, in the new version of OpenCV under this [file](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/dnn/src/nms.cpp)

```
static inline float rotatedRectIOU(const RotatedRect& a, const RotatedRect& b)
{
    std::vector<Point2f> inter;
    int res = rotatedRectangleIntersection(a, b, inter);
    if (inter.empty() || res == INTERSECT_NONE)
        return 0.0f;
    if (res == INTERSECT_FULL)
        return 1.0f;
    float interArea = contourArea(inter);
    return interArea / (a.size.area() + b.size.area() - interArea);
}
```

And because I am using older OpenCV version I tried only to copy the code as it seems not to be dependent on any other resources. The code runs very smoothly. However, the result is astonishingly wrong I am not sure why.

[image]

Comment: btw, that's the IoU for the rotated rects, not the ellipses

Comment: but isn't `cv::RotatedRect` is what `cv::fitEllipse()` returns? shouldn't be ok?

Comment: yes, but the ellipse is inscribed into that rectangle. So no, it's not ok

Comment: then what formulae or functions should I follow in order to calculate ellipses' IoU? any recommendation?

Comment: That's not trivial. The easiest way is to draw the white ellipses on two different black images (of the same size), and count the number of white pixels they have in common (logical AND).